# What implementation of SafeHandle should I use for process handles?

Tags: c#

This afternoon has been a crash course for me in terms of handles, Safe handles, PInvoke and many other things.  I think its slowly sinking in, however I'm still struggling with a couple of concepts:

**How do I know what implementation of SafeHandle I should use with different handle types?**

Specifically, what implementation of SafeHandle should I use with process handles (such as those in the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` structure returned from a call to CreateProcess?

The only two public implementations that I can see are `SafeFileHandle` and `SafeWaitHandle` - neither of these seem to be appropriate in this case.

Which should I use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SafeWaitHandle is the appropriate one.  A process handle is in fact a waitable handle.  You can call WaitForSingleObject() on it and it will block until the process terminates.  The ReleaseHandle method calls CloseHandle(), as required.  Are you sure that the Process class doesn't already do what you need?

Comment: I need to pass a handle to a socket to the child process as StdIn - the `Process` class obviously wont let me do this!  Also the process class has an issue with environment variables being lower case in versions of .Net prior to v4.0 (also I want to understand how it all works)

Comment: Erm, so you are actually talking about a socket handle?  You cannot redirect process I/O through sockets btw, that requires pipes.  Not sure what you're trying to do though.

Comment: I was going to have a go at implementing FastCGI in .Net (http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fcgi-spec.html) - as far as I can tell the handle passed to StdIn can be a handle to a socket (although that entire section did kind of confuse me - my approach was going to be try it and see what happens!)